# Update values in nested array based on another array

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have a `mainArray` and `data` array:

```
const mainArray = [
  {
    name: 'Name 1',
    values: [
      {
        key: 'A',
        value: 0,
      },
      {
        key: 'B',
        value: 0,
      },
                {
        key: 'C',
        value: 0,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: 'Name 2',
    values: [
      {
        key: 'D',
        value: 0,
      },
      {
        key: 'E',
        value: 0,
      },
                {
        key: 'F',
        value: 0,
      },
    ],
  },
];

    const data = [
  {
    key: 'A',
    value: 4,
  },
  {
    key: 'C',
    value: 6,
  },
  {
    key: 'E',
    value: 1,
  },
];
```

I want to update each value in mainArray by value present in data array (based on 'key' property).
I was trying to use lodash filter and find but it doesn't work fine for me.

Comment: This sort of question gets asked at least once a week.  Did you do any research?  Have you made any effort on your own?

Comment: convert the data to an object for fast lookup. run a nested loop and update the mainarray

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with nested loop,
i just made a try and here is the working output,

```
data.forEach((e)=>{
  mainArray.forEach((par)=>{
    par.values.forEach((subchild)=>{
      if(subchild.key== e.key)
        subchild.value=e.value;
    });
  });
});
```

this is working as expected, verify them as follows,

```
    console.log(data);
    mainArray.forEach((par)=>{
      console.log(par);
    })
```